# ocaml function takes function as parameter and output a function

Tags: ocaml

I need to find a way to combine two functions and output them as one.

I have the following code where take in a list of function `('a->'a) list` then output a function `('a->'a)` using the `List.fold_left`.

I figured out the base case, but I tried a lot of ways to combine two functions. The output should have the type `('a -> 'a) list -> ('a -> 'a)`.

example output:

```
# pipe [] 3;;
- : int = 3 
# pipe [(fun x-> 2*x);(fun x -> x + 3)] 3 ;;
- : int = 9 
# pipe [(fun x -> x + 3);(fun x-> 2*x)] 3;;
- : int = 12
```

function:

```
let p l = 
  let f acc x = fun y-> fun x->acc   in  (* acc & x are functions 'a->'a *)
  let base =  fun x->x in
    List.fold_left f base l
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you know that you have to use a left fold, you now have to solve a fairly constrained problem: given two functions of type `'a -> 'a`, how do you combine them into a single function of the same type?

In practice, there is one general way of combining functions: composition. In math, this is usually written as `f ∘ g` where `f` and `g` are the functions. This operation produces a new function which corresponds to taking an argument, applying `g` to it and then applying `f` to the result. So if `h = f ∘ g`, then we can also write this as `h(x) = f(g(x))`.

So your function `f` is actually function composition. (You should really give it a better name than `f`.) It has to take in two functions of type `'a -> 'a` and produce another function of the same type. This means it produces a function of *one* argument where you produce a function taking *two* arguments.

So you need to write a function `compose` (a more readable name than `f`) of type `('a -> 'a) -> ('a -> 'a) -> ('a -> 'a)`. It has to take two arguments `f` and `g` and produce a function that applies both of them to its argument.

I hope this clarifies what you need to do. Figuring out exactly how to do it in OCaml is a healthy exercise.

Comment: i know how the function is calling, but I cant find the one to call acc first the call x, is there a example that a function take 2 function as parameter and output as a function?

Comment: Ah. I'm not quite sure what you mean. If you want to take two arguments and output a function of a single argument, you could write something like `let compose f g = fun x -> ...`. Here `f` and `g` are normal arguments; the result is a function expecting a single argument `x`. Does that help?

Comment: let f acc x =  fun y -> x(acc), but now the function takes in (('a -> 'a) -> 'a) list -> 'a -> 'a

Comment: it works now as you told me to define a compose function, thx. But is there a way not writing addition fucntion?

Comment: I think its because the let f acc x function name problem, if I name it something else, I can just do the compose function inside

Comment: @user1968057 you need to ask yourself what is the parameter `y` in your existing code. What is its purpose? Why did you put it there, instead of placing it in last position? Why do you have 3 parameters (`acc`, `y`, `x`)? You also need to look at the compose definition in the explanations, and see how many variables there are in there.